# I Used Shift + L to select all objects in common.. how do I apply a material to all of those now?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I did Shift + L to select objects with the same default material, but now how do I apply a material to all of those?

It will only apply a material to the original one I wanted to compare the other objects with.

Answer (score 0):

You select all the objects that you want to apply material to, with the one that you already applied material to as the last selected one, then hit CTRL+L (make links) and choose Materials from drop down list.